# Hide Field when value is chosen from dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Forms in Register.cshtml

```
   <div class="form-group" id="Nick">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nickname, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nickname, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="Company">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompanyName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group" onchange="Show()">
        @Html.Label("Select Your Role", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label", @id = "ddlRoleId"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Role, Model.RoleList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",  @id = "ddlRoleId" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function Show() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlRoleId'),
            Nickform = document.getElementById('Nick'),
            CompanyForm = document.getElementById('Company');
        ddl.addEventListener('change', function () {
            if (this.value === '1') {
                Nickform.style.display = 'none';
                CompanyForm.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                Nickform.style.display = 'block';
                CompanyForm.style.display = 'none';
            }
            if (this.value === '2') {
                CompanyForm.style.display = 'none';
                Nickform.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                CompanyForm.style.display = 'block';
                Nickform.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
        };
</script>
```

I want when I choose a Role one from the two Forms (Company/Nickname) to hide.
But the code above don't work. I can't find where I make a mistake. May be at DropDownList. But if someone can help me, it would be well.

Comment: why not try jquery? 

$( "#ddlRoleId" ).change(function() {
  //your code
});

Comment: and remove @id = "ddlRoleId" from the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 points.

you have 2 ids the same. label and the dropdown has id `ddlRoleId`. I assume you want the label `for="ddlRoleId"` instead of `id="ddlRoleId"`

Also, I cant see where you are calling `Show()`. try replacing that line with `window.onload = function () {`. or add `window.onload = Show();` after the show function.

so:-

```
window.onload = function () {
    var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlRoleId'),
        Nickform = document.getElementById('Nick'),
        CompanyForm = document.getElementById('Company');
    ddl.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.value === '1') {
            Nickform.style.display = 'none';
            CompanyForm.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            Nickform.style.display = 'block';
            CompanyForm.style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (this.value === '2') {
            CompanyForm.style.display = 'none';
            Nickform.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            CompanyForm.style.display = 'block';
            Nickform.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
 };
```

Comment: I call Show() at the bottom of the Register.cshtml at section Scripts part